# .NET regular expression parameters recognizer

Tags: .net, regex, parameters

I try to write a .NET regular expression for recognising the "parameters" in my code language:

For example in my code language I have this single line, but in general don't think that this is a code-language, this is a string line...

```
SET A = MyFUNC (@param1,@param2) #this is a in-line comment and this 2 parameter not wil be recognized @param3 @param4
```

I need to match `@param1` and `@param2` that are the parameters in my language.

I need to perform the search using a .NET regular expression.
Is this possible?

Comment: Could you post your attempt please?

Comment: While it's technically possible without a parser, it gets quite complex very quickly... What if you have `MYFUNC("@CONSTANT", @param2)`, or even worse `MYFUNC("@CONSTANT\"", @param2)` or even worseR you want to support multiline comments... Normally you should "invest" an year of your life and study antlr :-)

Comment: Of course we have already "invest"...a year and more for the parser.. :) ... that work well..this search, regex is needed only for the color pourpose. In your example the parse retur one or more error..Here i need only to find match with word that start with @ ... I try this solution: "@\\w+" that seem to work... tks very much, Marco Bosco

Answer (score 0):

The regex is this:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<!#.*)@[A-Za-z0-9_]+");
var res = rx.Matches(str).OfType<Match>().ToArray();
```

it will return a match for each parameter before the #, but as I've told you in the comment, it's so much primitive that caveman with a club are modern in comparison.

It looks for `@ + letters/numbers/_` not preceded by a `#` (the `(?<!#.*)`).